# Where to implement i2c essentials

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, device, i2c

I am currently working on building a i2c driver from scratch for a 9 axis sensor that performs a variety of functions, all accessible on registers via i2c.

I have a few resources on how to write i2c drivers for linux, and my problem is that it is unclear where everything must go. So far I have a driver sketched out, by no means functional.

```
static struct i2c_device_id sps_id[] = {
    {"SPS_test", 0},
    {}
};

static struct i2c_driver sps_test_driver = {
        .driver = {
            .name ="SPS_test",
       },
    .probe = sps_probe,
    .remove = sps_remove,
        .id_table = sps_id;
};

static int __init sps_test_init(void)
{
        return i2c_add_driver(&scout_test_driver);
}
```

I know also that the `.name` field provides the linkage to the next bit of code which identifies my specific i2c address.

the following taken from http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.31/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices::

```
   static const unsigned short normal_i2c[] = { 0x2c, 0x2d, I2C_CLIENT_END };

   int __devinit usb_hcd_pnx4008_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
  {
          (...)
          struct i2c_adapter *i2c_adap;
          struct i2c_board_info i2c_info;

         (...)
         i2c_adap = i2c_get_adapter(2);
         memset(&i2c_info, 0, sizeof(struct i2c_board_info));
         strlcpy(i2c_info.name, "isp1301_pnx", I2C_NAME_SIZE);
         isp1301_i2c_client = i2c_new_probed_device(i2c_adap, &i2c_info,
                                                    normal_i2c);
         i2c_put_adapter(i2c_adap);
         (...)
 }
```

If I follow the explaination correctly, I would prefer to go this rout so that I may use an adapter that is already written, lessening my work load and minimizing risk.

Now I need to know, where do I make my own code to do the that kind of probe? Is this similar to the `.probe` member of the `struct i2c_driver` ? are they the same ?

Comment: Leveraging an existing driver is definitely the best way to start.  Since I2C devices are not normally discoverable via HW, you will need to get them to enumerate via sofware.  To get the probe function to be invoked, it will need to be registered as a platform device.  Look at the platform device model and how other platforms are registered.  You can search the kernel tree for platform_add_devices() and platform_device_register().

Comment: I've decided to try and use a `struct i2c_board_info` with one field `{I2C_BOARD_INFO(foo,i2c_id_for_foo), /*No IRQ*/ }` instead of the latter, for simplicity. Do you know where I should use this? It would seem that they reside in <kernel>/arch/arm/mach-xyz123 for my particular board, should I create a new directory like "mach-mystuff"?  thanks Peter.

Comment: I think that would do.  Be sure to put __init in front of the initializer.  You can look at how the other board files do it.  In fact, I would just create this with some printk()'s (leave out all the other code) and see if it gets invoked.  Then try the platform/driver skeleton code, then put the I2C code in after all the other code is working.  You could get the initial stuff working quickly.

Comment: Brilliant, I will try that... as soon as I can build. Thank you!